# Magento 2 how to login user in specific store programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

How can I login customer in specific store programmatically in Magento 2?
I've tried to override **execute** method of

> Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost

and did something like this:

```
$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore("store_code");
$store = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode("store_code");
$this->httpContext->setValue("store", "store_code", "default");
$this->storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);

$customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
$this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's more difficult as You think.
You cannot set cookie store or something that. 
As work around,  you can post credentials to specific store, by ajax query, and if response has succesed - you can redirect customer to that store.

Comment: Thank you for giving direction. I've send post request via ajax with customer email to my controller, where I check which customer group customer is and according to this return desired store. And then send post with credentials to login in that store.